# YouTube natively in Swift app?

Tags: swift, swift3, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Ok I have looked at similar Qs and know that YouTube has an API- https://www.appcoda.com/youtube-api-ios-tutorial/

However I am confused as to why people continue using the openUrl route (meaning t either opens in YT app or safari) if this is, in fact, possible-

I want to display/let users browse through ONLY. a certain YouTube channel natively in my app. Views need to be able to be registered so I need a clean/boiler plate solution or will go the openUrl route..

Is this possible? I thought to use a web view and pull up the channel but that could result in user just navigating out of YT channel and having a random web view in my app, plus not sure whether there is load times there.

Is the best method openurl? Or native possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use a webview.

You can also query Youtube's API (E.g. `listitems` endpoint: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to get a list of videos (what I have done in some apps) and then when the user taps the element, use `YTPlayerView` (available at https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

Example:

```
class YTPlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: YTPlayerView!
    var selectedVideo: YouTubeVideo?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let video = selectedVideo {
            title = video.title
            videoView.load(withVideoId: video.videoId)
        } else {
            // Video not selected
        }
    }

}
```

`YTPlayerView` will use a webview internally to play the video (It's the only method allowed by YT's tos)